uniqueness of generators of Lie groups
Are the generators of any particular Lie group always unique? Let's take $SU(3)$ group as an example. It does have 8 generators which are explicitly written as eight $3\times3$ matrices in the literature. However, is this set of matrices unique? Or one is able to find another set of 8 matrices as generators? If so, would that mean that one would be able to find an infinite set of generators?

No, they're very far from unique. For example you can replace any pair of generators $X, Y$ by $\frac{X + Y}{2}, \frac{X - Y}{2}$. (Also, you're using physicist terminology; what physicists mean by "generators of a Lie group" is what mathematicians would call "a basis of the Lie algebra.") There are uncountably many sets of generators in general.

If by "set of generators" you mean a spanning set of elements of the Lie algebra, then of course you can have an infinite set of generators: just add infinitely many elements to any finite set of generators. If you mean a basis (so, linearly independent), then no: any basis for a given vector space has the same size, and this is an invariant called the dimension of the space. Of course bases for real or complex vector spaces are not unique.

Qiaochu has already answered this in the comments but I wanted to put together a longer answer as I see this confusion fairly regularly here.
It is quite common in Physics to use "the" a bit too liberally for a mathematician's taste. In effect, making a choice but hiding that a choice had to be made. For example, to represent something as matrices in the first place you have to make a choice of basis.
In this case we are talking about generators of a Lie group for which the mathematical term would be a basis of the Lie algebra. Well, at least that is my understanding of how physicists generally use this term. I have occasionally seen it used more restrictively, for example that you could write any element of the Lie group as a product $\exp(a_1X_1)\cdots\exp(a_nX_n)$ which I am not sure holds over every (or even any in some cases) basis especially when we move away from compact Lie groups.
Keeping with the basis of the Lie algebra definition however we can see there must be uncountably infinitely many choices of bases we can choose as there are for any real vector space. The ones I assume you are referring to (the Pauli matrices, Gell-Mann matrices etc.) are a fairly natural choice of course although they are implicitly depending on our earlier choice to represent elements as matrices. Indeed they are not far from the default choice a mathematician would make. You are, in effect, taking a basis derived from the root space decomposition of the Lie algebra.
Specifically the elements $E_{i,j}$ with a 1 in the $(i,j)$th slot and 0's elsewhere are root vectors for the Cartan subalgebra defined as the diagonal matrices (this is a choice but all other choices are conjugate). Then our basis for $\mathfrak{su}(n)$ starts with $X_{i,j} = E_{i,j} - E_{j,i}$ and $Y_{i,j} = i(E_{i,j} + E_{j,i})$ which gives us skew-Hermitian elements. A physicist would multiply these by $i$ to make them Hermitian instead of course.
The remaining elements then form a basis of the diagonal matrices. In maths, it would be most common to take the simple coroots as a basis. These would be $H_{i} = i(E_{i,i} - E_{i+1,i+1})$. In physics, they instead take an orthonormal basis. Indeed I think they simply apply Gram-Schmidt orthogonalisation to the coroot basis and indeed they normalise our root vector basis elements as well.
The result is that the physics basis is an orthonormal one (for the inner product on $\mathfrak{su}(n)$ derived from the Killing form) which is why the numbers are a little more complicated than my maths basis (which I might loosely call a Cartan-Weyl basis). Even so there are many choices of orthonormal basis.
